# Cloud SQL + Compute Engine: will performance will be good?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

From a Google Compute Engine VM is it recommended to connect to Google Cloud SQL or use another Compute VM for DB separately and connect it?

Since Cloud SQL instances don't have private IP addresses, the connection between GCE VM and Cloud SQL uses public IP addresses. Will performance of applications like Wordpress, ecommerce or customized java application running compute engine be good when using Cloud SQL as a back end?

Comment: One great thing is you can use the internal IP of the GCE instance, don't have to use external IP as with Cloud SQL. This could improve the latency slightly

Comment: thats great info. Is it possible to use internal IP between different zone ?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it seems like it. From the diagram, shows that virtual switches can be used to cross over regions : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking . Please post here if you find it to work etc. Another benefit worth mentioning is the security improvement, not having to use external IP.

Answer (score 2):

The performance of Cloud SQL depends vastly on what your application does, and what you are comparing it to. There are several aspects to think about:

**Network latency**

Latency is likely critical for your application if you do a large number of small, cached queries serially and require millisecond scale response times.

Generally latency increases the further a connection has to travel. The lowest latency will be when running MySQL on the same VM as your application. Next would be MySQL running on another VM in the same zone, and after that Cloud SQL.

**Disk throughput**

Disk throughput is likely critical for you if your database is too large to cache in memory or is write-heavy.

MySQL running on GCE can [scale disk throughput with the size of your disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#pdperformance) and is generally very fast. Cloud SQL has no limit on your throughput, but might not be so quick as it is replicated across multiple zones to ensure high availability.

**CPU power**

CPU power is likely to be critical if you are read-heavy and your database fits in memory, or you have very CPU intensive queries.

Both Cloud SQL and GCE can scale to instances with more Powerful CPUs. This is much simpler to do in Cloud SQL.

**Features**

While the above generally points to higher performance when running MySQL on GCE, doing so comes at a great loss of reliability and features. GCE Persistent Disk is only available within a single zone, so if that zone is unavailable your database is unavailable. Cloud SQL has disk-level replication to allow your instance to move to a different zone if needed. Moreover Cloud SQL provides automatic backups, automatic upgrades and other management features.

Comment: I used Google SQL during development, but had terrible rps, about 30 max. Once I changed and used GCE with mysql it jumped to over 1000 rps, with nothing else changed. Just something to mention related to the difference between the two I have experienced.